# Чтение всех файлов с помощью bat

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

Создать командный файл, который будет постранично читать все текстовые файлы (* .ТХТ), содержащиеся в текущем каталоге

Пока что написал такой код, но он не работает

```
@ECHO OFF

for  %%f IN (*.txt) DO (
set str=<%%f 
echo %str% )

pause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
chcp 1251

for  %%f in (*.txt) do (
type %%f
echo.
)
pause
```

Перебор файлов с заданным расширением.

Команда `chcp` для изменения кодировки на *кириллицу*, задан параметр `1251`.
Команда `type` выводит содержимое текстового файла.
Команда `echo.` без пробела между командой и точкой делает перенос строки после отображения файла.

Comment: Огромная благодарность за код и пояснения.